# Problem extracting values from AggregateResult, results in NULL

Tags: list, map, string, set, aggregateresult

I admit that I haven't done too much with the AggregateResult object but I can't figure out how to successfully extract the values to add to a Set.

Here's my code:

```
public List<AggregateResult> nonUniqueAcctStringCollection {get;set;}
public Set<String> acctNameStrings {get;set;}

public DataCleanupDashboardController() {
    nonUniqueAcctStringCollection = [select name from Account group by name having count(name)>1];
    system.debug('nonUniqueAcctStringCollection= '+nonUniqueAcctStringCollection);
    for(AggregateResult ar : nonUniqueAcctStringCollection){
            //acctNameStrings.add(String.ValueOf(ar.get('Name'))); - NULL pointer exception
            //acctNameStrings.add((String)ar.get('Name')); - NULL pointer exception
            system.debug(String.ValueOf(ar.get('Name')));
    }
}
```

However on my 2nd debug, all of the values are successfully outputted

- 09:16:07:150 USER_DEBUG [13]|DEBUG|Account #1
- 09:16:07:150 USER_DEBUG    [13]|DEBUG|Account #2
  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to verify Null before performing any operation on the object.

So, `ar.get('Name')` is returning null and you are using `String.valueOf()`, that's why it is giving NullPointer Exception.

Secondly, instantiate `acctNameStrings` variable before adding items to this Set.

```
public List<AggregateResult> nonUniqueAcctStringCollection {get;set;}
public Set<String> acctNameStrings {get;set;}

public DataCleanupDashboardController() 
{
    acctNameStrings = new Set<String>();
    nonUniqueAcctStringCollection = [select name from Account group by name having count(name)>1];
    system.debug('nonUniqueAcctStringCollection= '+nonUniqueAcctStringCollection);
    for(AggregateResult ar : nonUniqueAcctStringCollection)
    {
        if(ar.get('Name') !=null)
        {
            acctNameStrings.add(String.ValueOf(ar.get('Name')));
            System.debug(String.ValueOf(ar.get('Name')));
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that... it even fails on the  if(ar.get('Name') !=null)

Comment: it is failing because of acctNameStrings

Comment: Thanks... should have instantiated - not sure how I missed that.